# UIView viewwithtag method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to learn some swift. 
I programmatically add labels. I want to change their properties later.

the viewwithtag method returns a UIView, how to I access my UILabel from this?

cheers

Comment: isn't UILabel an UIView? think about it

Comment: It is answered by Adam, Midhun, and iPatel.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to use a typecast. This code will do it:

```
    if let theLabel = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel {
        theLabel.text = "some text"
    }
```

Comment: "var theLabel : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel" Shouldn't it be using ? as you can't be sure viewWithTag is not returning nil?

Comment: @Konrad77 well spotted. I have edited the answer

Comment: It gives error, `'UILabel?' does not have a member named 'text'`

Comment: @Virussmca read about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496).

Comment: it gives fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . i am using Xcode 9.1

Comment: @Coder Impossible to get that error using the code from my answer. It uses conditional unwrapping to prevent that exact error.

Answer (score 5):

[viewWithTag:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:) returns a UIView, you need to typecast it to `UILabel`.

```
var yourLabel : UILabel = yourView.viewWithTag(yourTag) as! UILabel;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to write as

```
var getMyLabel : UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(tagValue) as UILabel;
```

Comment: it gives `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` . 
i am using Xcode 6.1